# Is it possible to change url route parameter with another value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have asp.mvc project. Currently routing is set to form following url's:

```
site/school/45
site/school/45/courses
site/school/45/teachers
site/school/45/courses/17
etc.
```

I want to change this '45' (id of the school) to more 'user friendly' name, for example to take 'Name' of school '45'.
Now action methods are like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int schoolId)
{ ...
```

Is it possible to change routing to display school name instead schoolID without changing action methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"without changing action methods" seems to be the most important part of your question, right?

Yes, you can. You may override `OnActionEcecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` method in your controller class to do name-id mapping for you. You need to do the following:

1. Implement base controller class, something like this:

   ```
   public class BaseController: Controller
   {
           protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
           {
               base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
               var shoolName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["schoolName"].ToString();
               var schoolId = ...; // Get school id from name somehow here
               filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("schoolId", schoolId);
           }
   }
   ```

   (I assume here that you will change your corresponding routing parameter name from `schoolId` to `schoolName` in Global.asax.cs / RegisterRoutes).
2. Update all your controllers by making them inherit not from `Controller` but from `BaseController`, like this:

   ```
   public class SomethingController: BaseController
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

After that everything should be working. You won't need to change your controller actions - `schoolId` parameter will be already at place when it will come to calling them.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a new route to the global routing to allow for a string name rather than just an int id.
The best option would be to create a new method that takes the school name and then (from the database or a cached object/dictionary) translates the name to the id then forwards to the int index method.

Something like this (not shown caching)

```
public ActionResult Index(string schoolName)
{
 var schoolId = SomeMethodThatGetsTheIdFromString(schoolName)
 RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = schoolId });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* achieve this with a custom model binder to figure out the id of the school based on the name and use this to 'bind' to your `schoolId` parameter.

However, I would suggest leaving your routing the way it is - if a school's name changes for example it would mean that all bookmarks would no longer work, or your url would appear incorrect.